# Using abstract classes in Matlab (without properties)

Tags: oop, matlab

Let we have one abstract class:

```
classdef ACalculation < handle

    methods (Abstract)
        [result] = calculate (this, data);

        plot (this, data, limX, limY);
    end

end
```

And some other classes that implements ACalculation

```
classdef Maximum < ACalculation

    methods
        function [result] = calculate (this, data)
            %...
        end

        function plot (this, data, limX, limY)
            %...
        end
end
```

To functions of implementation class i give all needed information, so i don't need any properties.
So it looks like I need static classes. But if I have static classes I have a problem with calling this functions.
I'd like to do something like that:

```
criteria = Maximum();
%......
result = criteria.calculate(data);
```

Is it bad way to use inheritance?
Should I ignore matlab advices to change functions to static?
What else could I do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that in this case, static interface implementation is quite a good pattern.
Define your classes in the following way:

```
classdef ACalculation < handle

    methods (Abstract,Public,Static)
        [result] = calculate (data);    
        plot (data, limX, limY);
    end

end

classdef Maximum < ACalculation

    methods (Public,Static)
        function [result] = calculate (data)
            %...
        end

        function plot (data, limX, limY)
            %...
        end
end
```

Then, you can write a function that expects an `ACalculation` type:

```
 function foo(acalc,data)
      assert(isa(acalc,'ACalculation'));
      acalc.calculate(data);
      acalc.plot(data,[100 200]);
 end
```

Then create a `Maximum` empty instance and pass it to `foo`:

```
 foo ( Maximum.empty(0), [1 2 3]);
```

If you want to change the calculation method, call

```
 foo ( Minimum.empty(0), [1 2 3]);
```

When you say that such a pattern will not work, you are thinking like Java/C#/C++ developer. But unlike in C++ where *static* and *virtual* keyword cannot coexist, Matlab has no such limitation, because everything is done at runtime, and an "instance" can be empty or an array of `n` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If `calculate` is a static method of `Maximum‘, you would use ‘result = Maximum.calculate(data)` to call it, without instantiating to `criteria`.

It's not (necessarily) a bad way to use inheritance, or bad advice from MATLAB.

Comment: But if I have also other classes (Minimum, Mean and so on) i'd like to choose somewhere in the beginning wich type is used and after that using some object of abstract class, without saying which exactly class it is. In this case I can't use static, isn't it?